# My image doesn't render when I pass the image source path as a props. Image renders when I give the image source path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]
This is the parent component. I created `data.js` and in that `data.js` I have exported products object where I have written id and img source path. I have posted the image and you can see the file structure there also. I tried both of the image source path from data.js and product.js but none of them work

```
const ProductList = () => {
    return (
        <div className='productlist'> 
            <div className="pl-texts">
                <h2 className="productlist_title">
                    Create & inspire. It's David
                </h2>
                <p className="productlist_desc">
                    David is a creative portfolio that your work has been waiting for. Beautiful homes, stunning portfolio styles & a whole lot more awaits inside.
                </p>
            </div>
             <div className="product-list">
                {products.map((item) => (
                    <Product key={item.id} img={item.img}/>          
                ))}
             </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    
//This is the child component
import './product.css'
    
    const Product = ({img}) => {
        console.log(img)
        return (
            <div className='product'>
                <div className="p-browser">
                    <div className="p-circle"></div>
                    <div className="p-circle"></div>
                    <div className="p-circle"></div>              
                </div>
                    <img className='p-img' src={img} alt="" /> 
                   //If I give direct img path then it works. I have sent img path in the props.
                   
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Product
```

Comment: Your `Product` component write correct, you have problem in parent component with image path or with something else. Share your parent component.

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I have included the parent component. Please let me know, if you need more information regarding the problem. I am new to this. So, my way of explaining the problem may be little weak. Thanks for looking into it

Comment: Please check using the browser Developer Tools: (1) Inspect an `img` element and see what it's `src` is set to, (2) Try to open that src URL yourself in a browser tab (prepend the servername + port + base path), (3) look in the Dev Tools Network tab for any `404` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to put images into your app. You have to pick one.

---

1. We can put images in public folder, and pass image's path to `<img />` (More info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder)

Let's say we have /img in public folder.

```
/public
  /img
    /ecommerce.PNG
```

Then we can show the image by give http path to image (`yourdomain.com/img/ecommerce.PNG`)

```
<img src="/img/ecommerce.PNG" />   // Notice there's no ../../ in the path.
```

---

2. We can import a file right in a JavaScript module (More info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

```
/src
  /img
    /ecommerce.PNG
```

Then we can show the image by

```
import ecommerceImage from '../img/ecommerce.PNG';

<img src={ecommerceImage} />
```

---

In your scenario, the quickest fix would be edit the products data into

```
const products = [
  { id: 1, img: require('../../img/ecommerce.PNG') },
  { id: 2, img: require('../../img/adminportal.PNG') },
  { id: 3, img: require('../../img/imagegallery.PNG') },
  { id: 4, img: require('../../img/netflix.PNG') },
];
```